# how to update value class css with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

i try to update value on class body with event onclick javascript and it's work but after refresh page index.php body class set to default value = "skin-blue"

**index.php**

```
<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
```

**warna.php**

```
<div class="container col-md-3">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-tittle"><b>Pengaturan Warna</b></h3>
        </div>

    <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" name="warna" checked onclick="warna_biru()"> Biru <small>(Default)</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" name="warna" onclick="warna_merah()"> Merah
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" name="warna" onclick="warna_kuning()"> Kuning
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="radio" name="warna" onclick="warna_hijau()"> Hijau
            </div>          
    </div>

</div>

</div>
<!-- js -->
<script type="text/javascript">
function warna_biru() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className ="skin-blue sidebar-mini";
}
function warna_merah() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className ="skin-red sidebar-mini";
}
function warna_kuning() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className ="skin-yellow sidebar-mini";
}
function warna_hijau() {
  var x = document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].className ="skin-green sidebar-mini";
}
</script>
```

Comment: try calling your function like so `onload="func()"`

Comment: @Teemu it appears the OP wants the changes to take place on-the-fly

Comment: Store the new class of `body` as a cookie. When the page is loaded/refreshed, set the class of `body` to that cookie value.

Comment: @chris97ong local storage should be used for such purposes, cookies are for server side info.

Comment: @chris97ong I guess calling the function on DOM init would be best rather using `browser leverage` or `cookies`.

Comment: @ImmortalDude And not misunderstanding the concept of the document?